# Click on Javascript Link using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I need to click on the "Visualizar cruzeiros" button on this site: https://www.disneytravelcenter.com/MIN-000000000031063/sites++disney-cruise-line++cruises-destinations++alaska++view-sailings++view-sailings/

Unfortunately, I cannot do it by simply using:

`visualizar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#jb-card-txt-blk-redirect-link-zone-' + zona + 'night-' + str(c)+ '.redirectLink')
 visualizar.click()`

Or using:

```
visualizar= driver.find_element_by_class_name('redirectLink')
visualizar.click()
```

Or using:

```
visualizar= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jb-card-txt-blk-redirect-link-zone-' + zona + 'night-' + str(c) +'"]')
visualizar.click()
```

How am I supposed to click on this button then?

OBS: The "zona" and str(c) are loop variables, but they don't change the result of the code, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer to my problem:

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="jb-card-txt-blk-redirect-link-zone-' + zona + 'night-' + str(c) + '"]')[2]
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using xpath `//a[contains(text(),'Visualizar cruzeiros')`? This should return more than one element, you need to get the second one.
Try to write a test case with selenium IDE, it may give you a hint how to access the element.

Comment: Trying your solution gave me this as return: 
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(text(),'Visualizar cruzeiros') because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(text(),'Visualizar cruzeiros')' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: My line of code:
visualizar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Visualizar cruzeiros')")[0]
visualizar.click()